# Pass many values for one label as parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

How I can pass many values for one label as parameter in SSRS2016?

My dataset looks like (I can modify VALUE column as needed):

```
LABEL VALUE
XXX   10, 12
YYY   11
AAA   90, 80, 70
```

so each row contains more than one value (with the same number of digits). I use it to filter dataset on report level. I don't want to show each value in separate row, because LABELs will be duplicated.

Here is one of my trial:

[image]

Comment: Fix your data structure, so you have a table with one value per label.  That is the right way to represent this data.

Comment: After it I will have duplicated labels in report parameter list.

Comment: You may use comma separated strings,If you do this you should use comma separated function as query level .

Comment: @Testtest11, I think you can pass a comma separated list of values in a nvarchar or varchar column in your dataset then in the report you can filter based on the selected values but without knowing the data you want to filter we can't tell you how.

Comment: Do you have any example? I pass this parameter to Tablix Filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your parameter to use the dataset you posted in the OP. Just be sure you remove each white space between the comma and the number.

```
LABEL VALUE
XXX   10,12
YYY   11
AAA   90,80,70
```

Then in the filter you just need to use `SPLIT` function in the tablix filter:

[image]

For `Value` use this expression:

```
=Split(Parameters!ParamX.Value,",")
```

Where ParamX is your Text parameter and `[Code]` is the column you want to filter `Fields!Code.Value`.

Also if your `Fields!Code.Value` is an Integer field you must convert it to a string in order to this works, so you can use the below expression in the `Expression` textbox:

```
=Cstr(Fields!Code.Value)
```

**UPDATE** Note you can filter a column with **ONLY** one value since `Split()` function takes `10,12` and lets the report evaluates the filter first using `10` then `12` and so on.

So this approach will filter a dataset like this:

```
Code    Row
 10      1
 11      2
 80      3
 70      4
103      5
```

So if you select in your parameter the label `AAA` it will filter the rows 3 and 4.

**UPDATE 2** Support for multi valued parameters.

If your parameter is set to `Allow multiple values` you have to use a mix of `SPLIT` and `JOIN` functions:

Replace the Value expression by the below:

```
=split(join(Parameters!ParamX.Value,","),",")
```

Comment: I get an error: Failed to evaluate the FilterValues of the Tablix ‘Tablix3’. (rsFilterEvaluationError)
----------------------------
An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted)

Comment: @Testtest11, Could you show us the tablix you are trying to filter?

Comment: I added screenshot to my question.

Comment: @Testtest11, are you trying to filter the same dataset that you are passing to your parameter?

Comment: I don't know if I understand it correctly, but I need to choose many parameters(AAA, XXX...), not only one (containing many values). Will this be working using this approach?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta - While dealing with multivalue parameter that needs to be passed into a dataset - If we want to filter the dataset then we should use SPLIT and JOIN. Whereas if we want to pass the multivalue param into the dataset param, then it is sufficient to use only JOIN. Is that correct?